# Test for null not catching in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Using C# ASP.NET web form. I am trying to test for null values in text boxes in the footer row of my GridVew to avoid SQL exceptions when Insert() is called.

CodeBehind

```
        protected void gvTask_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName == "FooterInsert" && Page.IsValid)
            {
                GridViewRow gvr = gvTaskDashboard.FooterRow as GridViewRow;
                if (gvr == null) { return; }

                // Get Controls

                DropDownList ddlEmployee = gvTaskDashboard.Parent.FindControl("ddlEmployee") as DropDownList;

                TextBox txtProjectID = gvr.FindControl("txtNewProjectID") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtReleaseID = gvr.FindControl("txtNewReleaseID") as TextBox;
                DropDownList ddlTaskCode = gvr.FindControl("ddlNewTaskCode") as DropDownList;
                DropDownList ddlstatus = gvr.FindControl("ddlNewStatus") as DropDownList;
                DropDownList ddlPriority = gvr.FindControl("ddlNewPriority") as DropDownList;
                TextBox txtDueDate = gvr.FindControl("txtNewDueDate") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtNotes = gvr.FindControl("txtNewNotes") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtCompDate = gvr.FindControl("txtNewCompDate") as TextBox;

                // Test for nulls
                if (txtProjectID == null || txtReleaseID == null || txtDueDate == null)
                {
                    // Throw error message
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "error", "alert('Enter Project ID, Release ID, and Due Date.');", true);
                }

                else
                {
                    // Initialize Insert Parameters
                    TaskDashboardSQL.InsertParameters.Clear();

                    TaskDashboardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("EmployeeID", ddlEmployee.SelectedValue);
                    TaskDashboardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("ProjectID", txtProjectID.Text);
                    TaskDashboardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("ReleaseID", txtReleaseID.Text);
                    TaskDashboardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("TaskCodeID", ddlTaskCode.SelectedValue);
                    TaskDashboardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("TaskStatusID", ddlstatus.SelectedValue);
                    TaskDashboardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("TaskPriorityID", ddlPriority.SelectedValue);
                    TaskDashboardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("DueDate", txtDueDate.Text);
                    TaskDashboardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("Notes", txtNotes.Text);
                    TaskDashboardSQL.InsertParameters.Add("CompDate", txtCompDate.Text);

                    TaskDashboardSQL.Insert();
                }
            } // end FooterInsert
} // end gvTask_RowCommand
```

When the page is loaded, the GridView is displayed as expected. In the footer row, I have empty text boxes for the ProjectID, ReleaseID, DueDate, Notes, and CompDate. Dropdown Lists for the other fields. The Employee ID dropdown is referenced further up the page outside of the GridView.

If I fill in the Project ID, Release ID, and Due Date, the Insert SQL kicks off just fine. But as the SQL table is built with these fields as NOT NULL, if they are left empty, I get the expected SqlException for trying to insert a NULL value into a column that does not allow nulls.

I tried catching the test for nulls with the `if (txtProjectID == null || txtReleaseID == null || txtDueDate == null)` block, but I still catch an exception on TaskDashboardSQL.Insert(); in my else block.

Is there something wrong with the if() statement that isn't catching the nulls correctly?

EDIT: I tried using `if (txtProjectID.Text == null || txtReleaseID.Text == null || txtDueDate.Text == null)` and I get the same SQLException in the else clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking if the `TextBox` is `null`, which is different from checking if the `Text` inside of it has a value. The text box is showing up regardless if someone has entered anything into it.

Consider evaluating `txtProjectID.Text` instead. Also, you could use `string.IsNullOrWhitespace` to check if someone just put a single space in it or left it blank.

Comment: Yep, try using string.IsNullOrEmpty or string.IsNullOrWhitespace. Also, what is TaskDashboardSQL?

Comment: The IsNullOrWhiteSpace did the trick. Working If statement was 
`if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtProjectID.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtReleaseID.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtDueDate.Text))`

And TaskDashboardSQL is my SQLDataSource.